# How can I give a GameObject velocity in a certain eulerAngles value in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2D [platformer game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_game) with Unity. The player is able to aim and fire in a direction. The only data that I have about the direction is a Z rotation value (`eulerAngles`). How is it possible to instantiate a bullet that has velocity in the direction that **the aiming pointer was pointing to** in the instantiation moment?

[image: Look at this image]

(The red line shows the aim direction)

Comment: Can you share your code please and tag me?

Comment: Can’t you use the value of the rotation of the object from which you are instantiating the bullet? That way using Instantiate you would have something like this :
`Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);`
from : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angularVelocity` will cause your object to rotate which is not what you are looking for.

If you have the angle on the `Z` axis - let's call it

```
float zAngle;
```

you can use e.g.

```
var direction = (Vector2)(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, zAngle) * Vector3.right);
```

or also

```
var direction = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(zAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(zAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad)).normalized;
```

and then use this as your

```
rb.velocity = direction * speed;
```

Comment: Hello. Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to convert any `Vector` to `Quaternion` is to use `Quaternion.LookRotation`.

```cs
Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector, Vector3.forward);
```

In your question, given that you have already determined the bullet model as well as your location. In the Quaternion section, the following value is appropriate.

**Note:** that the `Vector3.forward` parameter specifies the rotation axis in the Z direction.

```cs
private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Shoot() => Instantiate($AnyBullet, $Position, Quaternion.LookRotation(rb.velocity, Vector3.forward));
```

Comment: Hello. The method you mentioned only instantiates a bullet. Can you please add the method to make the bullet move?

Comment: @Matinmohammadi Your question was related to bullet creation, add a script to the bullet to move it and put `transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime` in update for simple test.  You can code different methods depending on the type of bullet.  If the first problem is solved, click the green tick and continue, ask in another question or send an email to Kian.tianxuan@gmail.com.  Thank you.